# Postgresql doesn't use GIN index for "?" JSON operator

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

By some reason index is not used for "?" operator.

Let's take this sample https://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/ :

```
  CREATE TABLE json_test (
  id serial primary key,
  data jsonb
  );

  INSERT INTO json_test (data) VALUES 
  ('{}'),
  ('{"a": 1}'),
  ('{"a": 2, "b": ["c", "d"]}'),
  ('{"a": 1, "b": {"c": "d", "e": true}}'),
  ('{"b": 2}');
```

And create an index.

```
create index json_test_index on public.json_test using gin (data jsonb_path_ops) tablespace pg_default;
```

Then take a look at plan of the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE data ? 'a';
```

There will be Seq Scan while I would expect an index scan. Could please somebody advise what's wrong here?

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table? An index will not be used for a table with 5 rows.

Comment: Good question! Real-world DB contains dozens thousands of entries and yes it turned out that Postgresql works in different way on tiny bases like that sample (please see my reply to jjanes below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html): "The non-default GIN operator class jsonb_path_ops supports indexing the @> operator only."  It doesn't support the `?` operator.

So use the default operator for jsonb instead (called "jsonb_ops", if you wish to spell it out explicitly).

But if your table only has 5 rows, it probably won't use the index anyway, unless you force it by `set enable_seqscan = off`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I rewrote my query using @> and it have started using an index. Actually I wasn't able to do so for my sample query SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE data ? 'a' because it seems there is no wildcards support in JSON but my real-world query can be rewritten in this way SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE data @> '{"b":{}}' what finds all "b" containing instances and do use index. And you were right in regards to size. It never use an index on sample db, but on my real-world one with dozens thousands of entries it works just fine.